# Hibernate trying to alter table before creating it

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

Simple issue here: I'm running Spring Boot 2.2.5 on a mySQL database with MySQL5Dialect. Everything was peachy until I've added @ManyToOne annotation to Slide entity referencing the User entity - now Hibernate can't create tables because it creates the users table and then tries to alter slides table which it hasn't created yet. What did I do wrong?

User:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String token;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private boolean emailVisible;
    private String phone;
    private boolean phoneVisible;
    private int cohortNumber;
    private String company;
    private String position;
    private String linkedIn;
    private String function;
    private String bio;
    private String membership;
    private Date membershipSince;
    private Date membershipUntil;
}
```

Slide:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "editor")
@Table(name = "slides")
public class Slide {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private boolean visible;
    private int order;
    private Date edited;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "editor_id")
    private User editor;

    private String title;
    private String text;
    private String picture;
}
```

Hibernate config specifics:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

And the error:

```
Hibernate: create table users (id integer not null auto_increment, bio varchar(255), cohort_number integer not null, company varchar(255), email varchar(255), email_visible bit not null, enabled bit not null, function varchar(255), linked_in varchar(255), membership varchar(255), membership_since datetime, membership_until datetime, name varchar(255), password varchar(255), phone varchar(255), phone_visible bit not null, position varchar(255), role varchar(255), surname varchar(255), token varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: alter table slides add constraint FKobqxptfxg36ls278o63ouq369 foreign key (editor_id) references users (id)
2020-08-11 14:27:48.201  WARN 8224 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table slides add constraint FKobqxptfxg36ls278o63ouq369 foreign key (editor_id) references users (id)" via JDBC Statement
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table '32293814_alumnicemba.slides' doesn't exist
```

Comment: I don't see any errors in your "errors".

Comment: Sorry, the core error is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table '32293814_alumnicemba.slides' doesn't exist

Comment: just try to run again the application. and it will work just fine. and majke sure that u have an interface SlideRepository

Comment: No, it will not work just fine. The problem happens with every run: Hibernate tries to alter table it hasn't created yet. Yes, of course I have the repository interface. Come on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem:

`private int order;`

"order" is not allowed as a field name here and Hibernate was encountering an error when trying to create the slides table but not logging that error. I've renamed the field to "sorting" and it works now.